# Вывод картинок по размеру div

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня мозг замерз) Я получаю размер div'а `$('.template').height()` и делю это на `(temph) / 150`(150 это размер картинки.).**Но размер картинки указан в виде 50% и она может менять свой размер**.

**Как мне получить размер первой выведенной картинки?** и **template** делить на размер картинки.

Примерно должно быть так: `(temph) / imgsize` **в итоге for прокрутится правельно даже если картинка меняет размер**.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
 var temph = $('.template').height();
 var res = (temph) / 150;
 var result = res.toFixed();
var theImages = ["http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg","http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/butterfly-wallpaper.jpeg","http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/HD-Wallpapers1.jpeg"];

for (var i = 1; i <= result; i++) {

var item = theImages[Math.floor(Math.random()*theImages.length)];
$('.template').append('<img src='+item+'><br>').hide().fadeIn(800);

}
});

</script>";
```

```css
.template
{
background-color:green;
width:100%;
height:1000px;
}
.template img
{
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="template"></div>
```

Comment: Мой магический шар подсказывает, что высота дива содержит в себе значение до загрузки картинок

Comment: Автор, какой главный вопрос? Я перечиываю и перечитываю, но не могу понять. DIV задан в 1к px по высоте, это так и должно быть и надо поместить в него столько картинок, сколько влезет?

Comment: Главный вопрос: получить размер первой выведенной картинки.Правельном ввиде.У нее указан  размер в процентах а нужно получить в пикселях.

Comment: @Doofy,да всё верно нужно поместить сколько влезит картинок.Но это должно работать и на маленких экранах и на больщих.То есть Responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить размер изображения можно после загрузки, при помощи события onload, а высоту элемента только после внедрения в документ

```js
template = $('.template');

images = [
  "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg",
  "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/butterfly-wallpaper.jpeg",
  "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/HD-Wallpapers1.jpeg"
];

(function put(v) {
  item = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
  
  image(new Image());
  
  function image(img) {
    img.src = item;
    img.onload = function() {
      template.append(img, '<br>');
      v += img.offsetHeight;
      console.log(template.height(), v);
      if(template.height() > v) { put(v); } else { img.remove(); }
    }
  }
})(0);
```

```css
.template {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.template img { width: 50%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="template"></div>
```

Comment: Это реальный размер картинки надо получить то что мы видим глазами.То есть : http://image.prntscr.com/image/8cc68a8d2fac41edbd22cb05dbcf9c2d.png

Comment: Еще такой прикол в логах пишет 1 раз 184 это правельный размер то что мне нужно в другой раз пишет 1440 это реальный размер картинки.

Comment: @Sauron, это из-за fadeIn, некоторые не успевают внедриться в DOM

Comment: Убрал fadein всё ровно так же.Убрал fadein всё ровно так же.

Comment: @Sauron, этот ответ устраивает?

Comment: Прощу проверить в маленком размере браузера выводит слишком много количеств картинок.

Comment: @Sauron, он выводит столько, сколько влазиет в 1000px. Что не так?

Comment: Скриншот:http://image.prntscr.com/image/23a901109d3944349430448fc62268ac.png  JS:https://jsfiddle.net/p5js9a2y/

Comment: @Sauron, что за бред? Изменил ширину template `3646px`, а на скрине изменена высота в это значение

Comment: Если задача стоит поместить в div сколько вместится изображений, не важно в ширину или в высоту, то нужно задавать правильные вопросы и не водить за нос людей. Эта задача решается совсем иначе, в основном с помощью css

Comment: Не ужели так сложно было понять что не написал...Это я решил с помощью max-height.