# For внутри function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему сперва срабатывает `alert('imageh:'+imageheight);` хотя перед ним стоит 
`alert('result:'+result);` ?

**Главный вопрос как `result` вывести на `imgeheight` ?**

```js
var result = 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= result; i++) {

  var img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg";
  img.onload = function() {
    $('.left').append(this);

    result = this.height;

    alert('result:' + result);
  }

  var imageheight = result;
  alert('imageh:' + imageheight);
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потмоу что `img.onload` асинхронная функция.
Для этого существуют функции обратного вызова

```js
var result = 1;
for(i = 1; i <= result; i++) {
  img = new Image();
  img.src ="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg";
  
  function getHeight(i, c) {
    img.onload = function() {
      $('.left').append(this);
      c(this.height);
      console.log('result:', this.height);
    }
  }
  
  getHeight(img, imageheight => {
    console.log('imageh:', imageheight);
  });
}
```

```css
img { width: 10%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="left"></div>
```

Comment: Такойже пример как и было сверху. **Я попробую объяснить так:** У меня есть `div(template)` внего нужно поместить сколько влезит изображении. **Таким способом:** когда первый раз `for` прокручивает мне нужно получить размер картинки далее его разделить на размер `div(template)` в итоге я получаю число сколько нужно вывести картинок передаю это на `result` `result = imagefirstheigh;` в итоге значение `result` меняется на значение количество картинок.и  `for ` прокручивается до количество картинок.`i <= result `

Comment: Почему именно через for? Вы уже сегодня задаёте почти одни и те же вопросы. [546369](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546369), [546381](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546381). В одном из них я дал ответ и спросил, пойдёт ли такой ответ. Какие проблемы? **Нельзя получить реальный размер изображения до тех пор, пока оно не будет загружено** и **Нельзя получить размер элемента `<img>`, пока изображение не будет вставлено в документ**

Comment: В начале `result = 1;` Так я говорю когда выведена первое изображение получаем ее размер делим на `div` и передаем это на` result`, далее `result` прокручивает дальще.

Answer (score 0):

Кусок

```
alert('result:'+result)
```

Выполняется в тот момент когда будет загружено изображение (изображение начинает загрузку на строке «img.src» и следующей строкой мы навешиваем на него событие ожидания загрузки), а выполнение строки

```
alert('imageh:'+imageheight)
```

начнётся сразу после загрузки страницы.

Answer (score 0):

`alert('result:'+result);` выведется только после загрузки изображения (событие `onload`). Интерпретатор не будет ждать события и выполнит код ниже сразу.

Как вывести - можно воспользоваться `Promise`:

```js
var result = 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= result; i++) {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Оборачиваем в обещание
    var img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg";
    img.onload = function() {
      $('.left').append(this);

      resolve(this.height); // Как только загрузится картинка, разрешаем обещание положительно и передаем в качестве аргумента результат
    }
  }).then(result => { // Как только результат будет найден, вызовется эта функция с результатом
    var imageheight = result;
    alert('imageh:' + imageheight);
  });
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left"></div>
```

Comment: Главный вопрос как result вывести на imgeheight ?

Comment: @Sauron, см. дополнение.

Comment: я поменял `.then(imgh => { result = imgh;` полученное разрешение картинки даю на `var result` в итоге for должен прокручиватся по числу высоты картинки.Но `result` всё ровно также 1 раз прокручивается.Почему?

Comment: Когда обещание разрешится (не раньше события `onload`, конечно), только тогда `result` переменится. Проходит первый цикл, создаётся `Promise`, проверка второй итерации **не** выполняется, т.к. обещание ещё не разрешилось. Вот и будет всегда одна итерация.

Comment: Так **Главный вопрос как result вывести на imgeheight ?** мне проста нужно когда вывелась первая картинка берем ее размер и засовываем в `result` примерно : `result = imageheight;`

Comment: То что вы мне придоставили сверху можно сказать проста убрали `alert('imageh:'+imageheight);`

Comment: @Sauron, что Вам не нравится? Результат находится и может быть переприсвоен к `imageheight` (правда зачем?). Если же Вам нужно **управлять циклом** - это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @Doofy, Такойже пример как и было сверху. **Я попробую объяснить так:** У меня есть `div(template)` внего нужно поместить сколько влезит изображении. **Таким способом:** когда первый раз `for` прокручивает мне нужно получить размер картинки далее его разделить на размер `div(template)` в итоге я получаю число сколько нужно вывести картинок передаю это на `result` `result = imagefirstheigh;` в итоге значение `result` меняется на значение количество картинок.и  `for ` прокручивается до количество картинок.`i <= result `